# React datatable with dynamic rows with editable cell and sorting

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-data-table-component

**Primary requirement - I will NOT use useTable package**

**What can be used - 1) Custom DataTable 2) React Data Table(RDT) [link here](https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/story/getting-started-intro--page)**

***The Problem -***
I am primarily using RDT and it gives all that is required for a simple datatable. Tweaking it I can achieve dynamic rows and custom behavior through custom components. I have also tried creating custom table and achieved the same. However, in both the cases, the problem is sorting gets messed up in editable cells while I try to type in anything in the editable cell text box.

*Scenerios*

1. If sorting is not done, then I can type in values in editable cell and by each index the value is populating
2. After entering value at any index and if I sort that column, sorting is done, but again while changing values at any index, that change reflects in other indexed cell and not in that particular index.

What did I try is shown as a code below. I have marked the place for handleChange function where actual, I think the problem is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo, useCallback } from "react";
import { dealerCaseLinkDataModel } from "../../../../utils/utility";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import Controls from "../../../../components/common/control";
import CustomButton from "../../../../components/common/customButton";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";

const CaseLinking = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [caseRows, setCaseRows] = useState(dealerCaseLinkDataModel);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Main Component ", caseRows);
  }, [caseRows]);

  /**
   * Definition of table columns and cell properties
   */
  const columns = [
    {
      id: "caseIdYearTo",
      name: "Transaction no",
      selector: (row) => row.caseIdYearTo,
      sortable: true,
      cell: (row, index) => inputComponent(row, index),
    },
    {
      id: "damageAmount",
      name: "Damage amount",
      selector: (row) => row.damageAmount,
      sortable: true,
    },
  ];

  const customStyles = {
    rows: {
      style: {
        minHeight: "72px", // override the row height
      },
    },
    headCells: {
      style: {
        paddingLeft: "8px", // override the cell padding for head cells
        paddingRight: "8px",
      },
    },
    cells: {
      style: {
        paddingLeft: "8px", // override the cell padding for data cells
        paddingRight: "8px",
      },
    },
  };

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} row - The object entity
   * @returns a JSX
   */

  const inputComponent = (row, index) => {
    return (
      <InputComponent
        row={row}
        index={index}
        caseRows={caseRows}
        setCaseRows={setCaseRows}
      />
    );
  };

  const addRowInTable = useCallback(() => {
    setCaseRows((oldData) => {
      return [...oldData, dealerCaseLinkDataModel[0]];
    });
  }, []);

  const onSort = (selectedColumn, sortDirection, sortedRows) => {
    setCaseRows(sortedRows);
  };

  const addBtnRow = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <CustomButton
        BtnText={t("Add")}
        variant={"contained"}
        sx={{
          borderRadius: "20px",
          fontSize: "12px",
          color: "white",
          textTransform: "Capitalize",
          minWidth: "75px",
        }}
        icon={<AddIcon />}
        type={"icon"}
        onClick={addRowInTable}
      ></CustomButton>
    );
  }, [addRowInTable, t]);

  return (
    <DataTable
      columns={columns}
      data={caseRows}
      customStyles={customStyles}
      subHeader={true}
      subHeaderComponent={addBtnRow}
      onSort={onSort}
    />
  );
};

export const InputComponent = ({ ...props }) => {
  const initialValue = undefined;
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  let { row, index, setCaseRows, caseRows } = props;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    row[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setValue(e.target.value);
    const result = caseRows.map((obj, i) => {
      if (i === index) {
        return {
          ...obj,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        };
      }
      return obj;
    });
    setCaseRows([...result]);
  };

  return (
    <Controls.Input
      name="caseIdYearTo"
      className="textField whiteBg"
      value={value || ""}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default CaseLinking;
```

Here - **setCaseRows** is the state for holding all the data(array of objects), **dealerCaseLinkDataModel** is the initial data for **caseRows**(array of object),
**addBtnRow** is the function to add a row dynamically(it also gets hampered while sorting is done)
**onSort ** is a function by RDT which gives us the current state of the data after sorting. I checked that the caseRows actually sets to sorting state data after this onSort is executed.

*Probable error - *

1. I guess the handleChange function messes up the index and the component re-renders
2. After onSort, it though gives us the sort state of data, I guess, I need to return a new array of sorted data.

I am pasting the UI as image if somehow it gives a better understanding

[image]

I am expecting the editable cell box should work as expected while sorting and behavior of rest of the cells will have no impact.
I am also open to custom datatable ideas/code

Any help is much appreciated